# Limit the amount of text that select-all keyboard shortcut highlights

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications, keyboard-shortcuts

When I press ctrl-a, and a textarea (or contenteditable div) has the focus, it just selects that text.

But when a normal div has the keyboard focus, ctrl-a selects all text in the browser, and I want it to just select the text inside that div.

I can suppress ctrl-a working completely by adding a keydown listener to the div, like this:

```
 onKeyDown: function (ev) {
   if (ev.key === 'a' && ev.ctrlKey)ev.preventDefault()
 }
```

But how do I also say: select the text in `ev.target` ?

Is there a higher-level way to approach this? I'm thinking that ctrl-a might not be the select-all keyboard shortcut, on all OSes and devices.
(UPDATE: It is Cmd-A on the Mac, and the above code does not catch it.)

Comment: `(ev.metaKey || ev.ctrlKey) && ev.key === 'a'`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<div id="div1">This is a div.</div>
</body>
<script>
document.addEventListener("keydown",  function (ev) {
   if (ev.key === 'a' && ev.ctrlKey)
    {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var range = document.createRange();
        var p = document.getElementById("div1");
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        range.selectNode(p);
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    }
    
 });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. That specifies ctrl-a anywhere will only highlight div1, which is slightly different. But I think by attaching the "keydown" event to `document.getElementById("div1")` it will work? Also it could be `var p = ev.target` to keep it more flexible?